# Trouble generating iOS certificates

Tags: ios, codenameone, ios-provisioning

I'm trying to get the Hello World app running on a iPhone, but have been getting a confusing error.  I've tried this 4-5 times over the last 4 days with the same results.  Here are the steps I have followed:

1- I started with a fresh NetBeans install (NetBeans 8.2 Patch 1 under Windows 7), installed the plugin (v3.6.0), and created a new CodenameOne Project named 'Hello' from the Flat Blue theme and the template 'Hello World (Bare Bones). I set the package name to something unique as required.

2- Then I went to developer.apple.com and revoked any certificates that were there, and deleted all of the appIDs and Provisioning Profiles.  There is one iPhone5 device specified.  I believe this should give CodenameOne a clean slate to work with.

3- Back with NetBeans and CodenameOne, I invoked the 'iOS Certificate Wizard', specified my AppleID/pswd when requested (yes they are valid!), and selected my iPhone device.  The next screen summarized the certs (2 of them) and an AppID to be used to generate the provisioning profiles.  On the next step, I get the error: "Could not create the appstore profile." with accompanying messages to the effect that "The Apple Developer website is undergoing maintenance", etc.  I've included the screen capture:

[image: screen capture of the error]

When I check [https://developer.apple.com/system-status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/), everything looks like it should be ok.  If I look at my Apple Developer Account, Codename One has generated an iOS Development Certificate and an iOS Distribution Certificate, but not any App IDs or Provisioning Profiles.

FWIW, the plugin is version 3.6.0 from the default update site (https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/repo/netbeans/updates.xml)

Has anyone else had this problem?  I'm at a loss as to what to try next.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Terry

Comment: Try to generate the certificate through `iOS Signing` that could be found by right-clicking your project and go to CodenemeOne Settings. Also, check to make sure you don't have any pending agreement to accept under your Apple Dev account.

Comment: I have no idea where you got https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/repo/netbeans/updates.xml from but that hasn't been the source to install Codename One for at least 2 years...

Comment: Shai, that's the library that was installed by default when I installed the NetBeans plugin.  What should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On trying to generate a certificate on my side, I experienced the same issue.

It's a generic 'come back later' message from Apple.

Contact Apple and I will do the same to let them know about the issue.

Their system status is an idle dashboard which is unreliable.

**Edit:**

On trying again, I clicked **Ok** on that message and proceeded. The certificates and Provisioning Profiles were generated successfully and the app works fine with the certificates.

Comment: In my case clicking OK took me back to the page that begins "The following certificates will be used to generate....".  However, I kept click OK 4-5 times and finally one of them worked and it generated the certs, App ID and provisioning profiles.  Now I have to try deploying the app :)  - thanks for the suggestions

Comment: So I hate to be a pain, but I can't seem to build, download and run the app. I have done 'Send iOS Debug Build' and then, on the codenameone build dashboard, I see "iOS Successful build - 'Hello' Took - 2:57 At - 11:17 Feb 15th 2017". (cont'd below in next comment.......)

Comment: I click on that, and then on the "Install on Device" button, it gives a page with a single green "Install" button, click that and I get "codename-one-appspot.com would like to install "Hello"", click "Install" and I get the message "Unable to Download App - "Hello" could not be installed at this time. Done - Retry" Pressing Retry of course fails.  I've double checked the device ID of the phone and it matches that on developer.apple.com.  Clearly I'm missing something fundamental here. :-(

Comment: Do you have a similar Store version of the app on your device?

Comment: Make sure the device is selected during the generation of the certificate and the provisioning profile. Since you already have a valid certificate now, just focus on regenerating a valid provisioning profile and reuse that certificate for all of your future apps.

Comment: I don't think there is a similar store version of the app on the device.  Can't check right now - won't have the phone available for a few days.  And thanks for the other advice about reusing the certs - would I do that using the same 'iOS Certificate Wizard' and choose not to overwrite the certs, or would I use the 'iOS Signing' tool? (and in the second case case, how would I find the  passwords CodenameOne used when creating the .p12 files?)

Comment: You can do it through any of the 2 tools and choose not to override existing certificate during the process. After installing the provisioning profile, make sure your certificate path is pointing to those certificates respectively. If the certificate is generated through codenameone, thehe password is simply the word 'password'.

Comment: OK, The final obstacle was the "ios.debug.archs=armv7" setting - turns out I'm running 32bit hardware (iPhone 5 and iPhone 4).  Thanks Diamond for the help.

Comment: Yes, blogged about it here https://www.codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-64bit-by-default.html